# relational schema node.js mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm making an API with Node.js which is for a money management App. I have my user schema as the following:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type:String,
    required: true
},
email:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    uniqe:true
},
password:{
    type:String,
    required: true
},

budget:{
    type:String ,
    required: true
},
currency: {
    type: String,
    required: true },

spendings: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Spendings'},

purchases :{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Purchases'},

debts: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Debts'} 
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

What I'm trying to do is get all the users' Debts (for example) but I couldn't figure it out. I only was able to create and get Debts with the userID. This is my Debts Schema:

```
const debtsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
debtsName:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
price:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
},
userID: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  }

  },
  {timestamps:true}
  );

  module.exports = mongoose.model('Debts', debtsSchema);
```

> AuthController

```
exports.getOneUser = (req, res, next) => {
const id = req.params.userID;
User.findById(id).populate('spendings').populate('debts').populate('purchases')
.then(doc => {
    if(doc) {
        console.log("From database", doc);
        res.status(200).json(doc);
    } else {
        res.status(404).json({
            message: "No data is found by provided ID"
        });
    }
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
        error: err
    });
})
}
```

Please note that I am new o Node.js and explain in detail. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get Debts data of a particular user, write a query on debts collection using userID.

```
Debts.find({userID: id})
```

If you want all the users data with their corresponding debts data,

```
User.find({}).populate('debts')
```

Comment: it first gave me an error saying `Assignment to constant variable` But I made the **userID** and **id** a var and it worked! thanks